# SQL doesn't get the correct records

Tags: sql

I have a problem with the SQL query below. It gets records that doesn't match certain "requirements".

Lets say the timestamp right now is **1501580316**. Then it still returns records with `whoisexpire` values over this value (such as `1509422400`). I think it's conflicting with the AND below with the `whoisupdate`, because I tried to see what value the `whoisupdate` was on these records and it returned 0. But I don't get why it still gets it when the AND above doesn't match.

```
SELECT * FROM domains
    WHERE tld IN ('com')
      AND (whoisexpire !='0' OR whoisexpire<=".time().")
      AND (whoisupdate=0 OR whoisupdate<=".time().")
      AND majrefd>=25
      AND majtf>=10
    ORDER BY whoisexpire
    LIMIT 25
```

Edit:

This is the SQL Query im trying:

```
SELECT * FROM domains
    WHERE tld IN ('dk')
      AND ((whoisexpire !=0 OR whoisexpire<=1501586177) AND (whoisupdate=0 OR whoisupdate<=1501586177 ))
      AND majrefd>=25
      AND majtf>=10
    ORDER BY whoisexpire
```

This is the result:
[image]

Look at how the values in whoisexpire are over 1501586177, when in fact it shouldn't be possible.

Comment: Can you illustrate with some example data that it's returning that you're not expecting (even if only the `whoisexpire, whoisupdate, majrefd, majtf` columns)?

Comment: Well it outputs records where the whoisexpire is above the current timestamp. However, I tried to put both those lines with OR in them in the same () and it seemed to do it.

Comment: @RowlandShaw please look at the edit.

Comment: So `whoisupdate=0` AND `whoisexpire !=0` are the two conditions that are passing, so that is doing what you've asked of it - it's not clear how that differs to what you want though

Comment: @RowlandShaw not really. Look at the <= statements. (whoisexpire) in this example, cant you see that it gets higher values than what is defined?

Comment: The statement `whoisexpire !=0 OR whoisexpire<=1501586177` will pass for any non-zero value of `whoisexpire` **OR** any value of whoisexpire greater than or equal to the time stamp (which were already included, as they are non-zero) - did you mean for that first clause to be `=` instead of `!=`?

Answer (score 1):

Your bracket order was out, this should fix it.

```
SELECT * 
FROM domains
WHERE ((whoisexpire !='0' OR whoisexpire<=".time().") AND (whoisupdate=0 OR whoisupdate<=".time()."))
AND majrefd>=25
AND majtf>=10
AND tld IN ('com')
ORDER BY whoisexpire
LIMIT 25
```

Comment: Thanks, I actually just tried something very similar to that.

Comment: alright dude, this makes zero sense. I just took a closer look and it appears as if not both cases works at the same time. Look at my edit in the question..